# Shared fonts in ActionScript 2?

Tags: actionscript-2

I've been looking around the internet for a tutorial regarding shared fonts. I can't seem to find a simple tutorial explaining the processes that are required, and what exactly is need to pull embedded fonts from a SWF into another movie. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bryan Langdon seems to have a great explanation of runtime font loading in AS2 here.  I just gave it a quick read and it makes good sense (FWIW).

http://bryanlangdon.com/blog/2007/03/22/loading-fonts-dynamically-in-actionscript-2-and-3/

Comment: Great resource, and tutorial! I've ran across many explaining this linkage, but since I'm new to AS2, it was harder to comprehend.

Comment: If you have any opportunity to use ActionScript 3 instead of AS2, I highly recommend it.  Not all work environments or projects allow it though.

Comment: Just reading through the AS3 setup seems a multitude better. I've worked with it bit before, and coming from more OOP languges like Java, it I think it would of suited me better for this project if I could of used it. Alas, my firm is still stuck in AS2 :S.

Comment: I just have one small question, and was wondering if you knew how to load and utilize the font from the shared library into the another file in FLASH CS5? Bryan's tutorial didn't explain that last part, and reading through the Main.as, I'm a bit lost. I'm not sure where to start with it? Any help would be great! Thanks.

Comment: Sure.  After you've used Bryan's strategy to load a SWF with the font definitions you need, use a TextFormat object to assign a font to a text field.  You have to refer to the font by name, using the name it was exported by in your (font library) SWF.  See: http://www.flashxml.net/using-text-fields-in-actionscript2-and-font-embedding.html